# How can I fix a Pokémon Crystal cartridge that erases the save file whenever I place the Game Boy down?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I have a question about the Pokémon Crystal cartridge I just bought. It saves and has got a new battery in it, but when I place the Game Boy down the game resets and has no saved file. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: can you confirm if this happens for other games, or just crystal?

Comment: I've only got Pokemon crystal on my gameboy color soo I can only confirm it as just crystal

Comment: If you shake the cartridge does the battery move? It sounds like it looked connection and thus the save

Comment: I can't really tell if it moves but the case around the board itself was loose when I got it and I have no tool to tighten it